# Jquery issue -- scrolling menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out why the second gallery doesn't scroll like the first one
Here's a link:

Here's the jQuery that makes it work:

```
$(function(){
var state = 0;
var maxState = 7;
var winWidth = $('#sub').width();

$('#sub').resize(function(){
    winWidth = $('#sub').width();
    $('.gallerybox,.container_element').width(winWidth-110);
    $('.container_element').scrollLeft((winWidth-110)*state);
}).trigger('resize');
$('#lefty').click(function(){
    if (state==0) {
       state = maxState;
    } else {
       state--;
    }
    $('.container_element').animate({scrollLeft:((winWidth-100)*state)+'px'}, 800);
});
$('#righty').click(function(){
    if (state==maxState) {
       state = 0;
    } else {
       state++;
    }
    $('.container_element').animate({scrollLeft:((winWidth-100)*state)+'px'}, 800);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both navigation bars have the same id. Hence, when you search for id in jQuery it will stop searching once it founds the very first result. So it won't get your second navigation tab.

Change the id, or use a class selector.

By the way, you should post the html here, not link the productive site